# if 2 channels on one page ie: if channel == "channel1"

Tags: conditionals, ifelse, multiple-channels

I am trying to display one entry (most recent) on my home page from 2 different channels.  So ChannelA and ChannelB.

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="weblogA|weblogB" limit="1" sort="asc" show_future_entries="yes"}
{if weblog == "weblogA"} display A {/if}
{if weblog == "weblogB"} display B {/if}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

The above worked on an EE1 site but but now on an EE2 site and channel does not work the same.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channelA|channelB" limit="1" sort="asc" show_future_entries="yes"}
{if channel == "channelA"} display A {/if}
{if channel == "channelB"} display B {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Which is the EECMS version? I'm asking because you say "channel", but your code shows "weblog". Version 2 uses `channel` and version 1 uses `weblog`.

Comment: sorry if that was confusing.  I used this method in an EE1 site and it worked fine, but I tried to use the same method using channels instead of weblogs and it didn't seem to work at all.

I am using EE2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `channel_name`

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channelA|channelB" limit="1" sort="asc" show_future_entries="yes"}
  {if channel_name == "channelA"} display A {/if}
  {if channel_name == "channelB"} display B {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

See first comment here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#comments

Comment: And that first comment reads "`{channel_name}` ...is a shorthand of `{channel_short_name}`"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using EE1 you'll want to use `weblog_short_name` or `weblog_id` in your conditionals.

```
{if weblog_short_name == "some_weblog_name"}
    ...
{/if}
```

OR

```
{if weblog_id == "1"}
    ...
{/if}
```

As Robson pointed out **"weblog" is specific to EE1.** So if you are using EE2 just replace the word "weblog" with "channel."